# Finding an inverse matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I should find the inverse matrix of the matrix:
 \begin{pmatrix}
  n & n & \cdots & n & n \\
  n-1 & n-1 & \cdots & n-1 & 0 \\
  \vdots &  &  &  & \vdots  \\
  2 & 2 &  0 &\cdots & 0 &  \\
  1 & 0 &  0 &\cdots & 0 &  \\
 \end{pmatrix}

for all integers $n$.

Now I could do this by basic Gauss elimination.. taking a unit matrix as our right side and working our way down but this matrix seems pretty interesting as if we look at the rows we can always factor something out.

From the first row we can factor out $n$ and we will get $1 1 1...1$, from the second we can factor out $(n - 1)$ and we will get $1 1 1...1 0$, third $(n - 2) 1 1 1...1 0 0$ and so on..
So we should be able to just factor out $n!$ and simplify the matrix a lot.

My question is: what´s the best way to work with this matrix now, when you want to find the inverse? How do you proceed when you have something factored out from the left side? Is it even a step in the right direction here?

Thank you.

Comment: I can think of two ways to do this. One where the inverse is given by computing Adjugate matrix over the determinant of the above matrix. Second, the way you mentioned. Since your question asks what's the best way to work with this matrix, I'm not quite sure I can answer that. But in the 3x3 case, you can use your suggested method and you'll get a nice inverse. This will suggest there's a general pattern where you can generalize it to an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: what I meant was something a little different... if I factor out the $n!$ from this matrix and take the unit matrix $I_n$ as the right side of our matrix, can I just simply use Gauss elimination and not worry about the $n!$? With this method we aim to achieve unit matrix on the left side and what is left on the righ side is our inverse but considering the $n!$ is only substracted from the original matrix and not from the unit matrix it should not work like this, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can write $A = D B J$ where $D$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $(n,n-1, \ldots, 1)$, 
$J$ the "antidiagonal" matrix with $J_{i,n+1-i} = 1$ for $i=1\ldots n$ and $0$'s elsewhere, $B$ the matrix with $1$'s on and above the diagonal, $0$'s elsewhere.  Note that $J^{-1} = J$, while $B^{-1}$ has $1$ on the main diagonal, $-1$ on the superdiagonal (i.e. $(B^{-1})_{i,i+1} = -1$).
Thus $$A^{-1} = J B^{-1} D^{-1} = 
\pmatrix{ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1\cr
          0 & 0 & \ldots & 1/2 & -1\cr
          0 & 0 & \ldots & -1/2 & 0\cr
         \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\cr
         0 & 1/(n-1) & \ldots & 0 & 0\cr
         1/n & -1/(n-1) & \ldots & 0 & 0\cr
}$$
i.e. $(A^{-1})_{i,n+1-i} = 1/i$, $(A^{-1})_{i,n+2-i} = -1/(i-1)$, all other elements $0$.